# Java Get time duration between 00:00:00 HRS and Now

Tags: java, date

I am trying to get a time duration b/w the 00:00:00 HRS of current day and Instant.now()

```
Instant startTime = Instant.now().minus(Duration.ofMinutes(????))
Instant endTime = Instant.now();
```

What should I pass here to get the 00:00:00 Hours of current day?

Comment: Do you have to use `Instant`? Why not `Date` or `Calendar` ?

Comment: mean are you trying to get time passed since today 00 AM?

Comment: You can do something like this LocalDate.now().atStartOfDay().toInstant(ZoneOffset.UTC)

Comment: Isn't the time between 00:00 and now just the current time?

Comment: @Vucko Yes, I have to use Instant

Comment: @DobromirM Not always, if there are time changes due to DST, they may be not the same.

Comment: @Vucko Why not `Date` or `Calendar` — because they're obsolete, and also terribly troublesome. See also [What's wrong with Java Date & Time API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1969442/whats-wrong-with-java-date-time-api)

Comment: @Vucko [Why do we need a new date and time library?](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-date-time.html) [Still using java.util.Date? Don’t!](https://programminghints.com/2017/05/still-using-java-util-date-dont/)

Comment: @Shibankar hen you need to tell us: 00:00:00 in which time zone? At least once per hour, sometimes several times per hour, it’s 00:00:00 in some time zone.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An instant is a moment on the timeline. It depends whether you want to take timezones and DST changes into consideration or not.

If you don't care about timezone or DST, you *could* do

```
LocalDateTime now = LocalDateTime.now();
ChronoUnit.HOURS.between(now.toLocalDate().atStartOfDay(), now);
```

The returned `long` is the number of hours between midnight and the current time. This will be by far in most cases the hour number as displayed by your wall clock. Also note that this code snippet does not make use of `Instant`, since and instant does not know about the human representation of time, like 00:00:00 midnight.

If you do care about timezone or DST, then you need to specify your timezone in order to adjust for time changes. For instance, within `Europe/Amsterdam` timezone, on March 29, 2020 at 02:00 wall clock time, the clock skips 1 hour because of DST (called "zomertijd" or "summer time"), so if `now` is 14:39 wall clock time, the number of hours since midnight is not 14 but 13.

You can then do something like this:

```
ZoneId zone = ...
Instant now = Instant.now();
Instant midnight = now.atZone(zone).toLocalDate().atStartOfDay(zone).toInstant();
long result = ChronoUnit.MINUTES.between(midnight, now);
```

Make sure you query `now()` once, otherwise you may get wrong results in corner cases.